# Скрыть / Показать по checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько чекбоксов и к каждому свой инпут, инпут должен скрываться и отображаться по чекбоксу, может кто подсказать красивое решение?

```css
.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: .7vw;
  margin-top: 0.625vw;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-image: url('img/check_tablink.png');
  background-position: -2.6vw -0.4vw;
}

.conditions_check {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.5vw;
  width: 44vw;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625vw 0.125vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  color: #170738;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega1" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega1"></label>
  <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega2" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega2"></label>
  <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega3" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega3"></label>
  <span>The user should repost a tweet with a hashtag</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function conditionClick() {
  //console.log(this.id, this.checked);
  var $input = $(this).closest(".conditions_check").next(".conditions_input").find("input");
  this.checked? $input.show() : $input.hide();
}

$(".conditions_check input[type='checkbox']").click(conditionClick).each(function() {
  conditionClick.call(this);
});
```

```css
.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: .7vw;
  margin-top: 0.625vw;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.conditions_check input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-image: url('img/check_tablink.png');
  background-position: -2.6vw -0.4vw;
}

.conditions_check {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.5vw;
  width: 44vw;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625vw 0.125vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  color: #170738;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega1" type="checkbox" hidden checked>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega1"></label>
  <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega2" type="checkbox" hidden checked>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega2"></label>
  <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega3" type="checkbox" hidden checked>
  <label for="conditions_check_telega3"></label>
  <span>The user should repost a tweet with a hashtag</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Почему то не хочет работать у меня ваше решение (

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев Вы, вероятно, не заметили, что я внес `span`-ы внутрь `label`-ов.

Comment: Все равно не хочет работать, плюс я же при помощи label стилизую свой чекбокс и если туда добавить span то такой ужас получается)

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев Об этом я должен был сам догадаться? В Вашем примере `label`-ов вообще не видно. На что Вы собираетесь кликать, чтобы изменить состояние чекбокса?

Comment: Я добавил стилизацию label-ов, надеюсь правильно.

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев Что у Вас за атрибут `checkbox`? Вы имели в виду `checked`?

Comment: Честно этот вопрос вводит меня в ступор, никак не могу найти куда именно Вы указываете.

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев `<`input id="conditions_check_telega2" type="checkbox" **checkbox** hidden`>`

Comment: Такой способ скрывать сам чекбокс я вычитал на хабре, вместо checkbox, должен быть checked?

Answer (score 2):

Удивительно, но это можно сделать и без js, зачем нам лишний раз грузить пользователя =) Вот очень красивое решение!

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input 3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Такой способ работает, только если они стоят рядом.

Answer (score 2):

> Есть несколько чекбоксов и к каждому свой инпут, инпут должен скрываться и отображаться по чекбоксу, может кто подсказать красивое решение?

Вот такое решение на `Javascript`

```js
var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
// Проходим по всем checkbox
chks.forEach(function(chk) {
  // Вешаем событие
  chk.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.closest('.conditions_check')
      .nextElementSibling
      .firstElementChild
      .classList.toggle('hidden'); // Добавлен класс или убираем
  })
})
```

```css
/********************  ********************/
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
/********************  ********************/
.conditions_check label> input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: .7vw;
  margin-top: 0.625vw;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.conditions_check label> input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.conditions_check  label>input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  background-image: url('img/check_tablink.png');
  background-position: -2.6vw -0.4vw;
}

.conditions_check {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.5vw;
  width: 44vw;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625vw 0.125vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  color: #170738;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="conditions_check">
  <!-------- label > input > span -------->
  <label for="conditions_check_telega1">
  <input id="conditions_check_telega1" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <label for="conditions_check_telega2"> 
 <input id="conditions_check_telega2" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
 
  <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span> </label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <label for="conditions_check_telega3">
   <input id="conditions_check_telega3" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <span>The user should repost a tweet with a hashtag</span></label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, правда с label я не понял, почему так, если я в лейбел добавляю span весь текст пытается уместиться в 30px, потому что именно размер чекбокса 30px на 30px.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант. А почему бы не перенести и так скрытый checkbox к input'y, все равно ведь его ни кно не видит, считай его нет. Так мы снова избавимся от скриптов

```css
.checkbox:checked ~ input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="conditions_check">
  <label for="conditions_check_telega1">
  <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span></label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input class="checkbox" id="conditions_check_telega1" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <label for="conditions_check_telega2">
  <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span></label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input class="checkbox" id="conditions_check_telega2" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">
  <label for="conditions_check_telega3">
  <span>The user should repost a tweet with a hashtag</span></label>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input class="checkbox" id="conditions_check_telega3" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что это ломает саму конструкцию скрытый чекбокс+лейбол, я добавил стилизацию, которую сперва не добавил, сожалею о своем поступке